# SML - prime factorization, building list error

Tags: list, recursion, sml, prime-factoring

I'm trying to write an SML function that will return a list of all the prime factors to a given number.  This will end up being a helper function to another function later on.

Originally the bigNumber is the number that I need to find the prime factors for and I pass in 1 less than that number as the divisor.  Here's an example on how I'd call it to find the prime factors for the number 100. `getPrimeFactors 100 99;`

I'm not too worried about if there are flaws with the algorithm right now, but if you spot any errors with it I'd be happy to listen.

My main problem is trying to pass the return values up the recursion chain as lists and then combining those lists as they meet up with other lists.

```
fun getPrimeFactors bigNumber divisor = 
    if divisor > 0 then 
        if (bigNumber mod divisor) = 0 then List.concat(getPrimeFactors (bigNumber div divisor) ((bigNumber div divisor) - 1), getPrimeFactors divisor (divisor - 1))
        else [getPrimeFactors bigNumber (divisor - 1)]
    else [bigNumber];
```

Running this gives me this error.
    C:.....\run.x86-win32.exe: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Error with 0
    raised at ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27

```
C:\.....\commonFactors.sml:3.39-3.160 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
    operator domain: 'Z list list
    operand:         'Y * 'Y
        in expression:
            List.concat
            ((getPrimeFactors (<exp> div <exp>)) (<exp> div <exp> - 1),
             (getPrimeFactors divisor) (divisor - 1))
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call List.concat on a tuple. The type of List.concat is

```
fn : 'a list list -> 'a list
```

That is, it takes a list of lists, concatenates *all* of those together, and returns the result. That's your error.

If, instead of using List.concat, we use the @ operator, we get a different error (which may look slightly different on your system):

```
File "test.sml", line 7, characters 14-53:
!         else [getPrimeFactors bigNumber (divisor - 1)]
!               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   'a list
! cannot have type
!   'a
! because of circularity
```

This error is because `getPrimeFactors` is supposed to return an `int list`, but here you're trying to stuff the result from `getPrimeFactors` into a list, thus getting `int list list`.

Comment: Thank you!  Changed List.concat from () to [] and works great.  I'm very new to SML and it's hard to find good resources, seems like there are far fewer than with other languages.

Comment: I can recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Programming-International-Computer-Science/dp/0201398206).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was curious here's the corrected code with the right algorithm.  Was able to fix the List.concat errors thanks to Tayacan.

```
fun getPrimeFactors big small = 
    if small > 1 then 
        if (big mod small) = 0 then List.concat[(getPrimeFactors (big div small) (big div small - 1)), (getPrimeFactors small (small - 1))]
        else List.concat[(getPrimeFactors big (small - 1))]
    else if big = 1 then nil
        else [big];
```

Comment: Yes, well, you don't actually need to use List.concat at all. You're only ever concatenating two lists together, so just use the `@` operator ;)

Also, your current problem: What happens when you run `getPrimeFactor 2 1`?

Comment: Is it more efficient to use the @?

Comment: And for getPrimeFactors 2 1 I get 2 which is correct according to this [link](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/factor/factor.html)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that you'd changed it to > 1 instead of > 0 ;)

Comment: No, I don't think it's necessarily more efficient to use @ (it might save you a little overhead from not building the one- and two-element lists), but it's definitely clearer what you're doing.